# How to get tooltip to show values for two time series at the same time?

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to have the tooltip show values for both series at the same time like depicted here: https://jsfiddle.net/bcmoney/w2oorj24/.
I have googled and tried different things, but nothing seems to work.
What am I missing? Thanks for a hint in the right direction :).

```
   var tooltip = {
      shared: true
   };
   var series= [{
      type: 'line',
      name: 'Count Act YTD',
      pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
      pointStart: Date.UTC(2019, 1, 28),
      data: [
0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
         ]
      }, {
      type: 'line',
      name: 'Count Plan YTD',
      pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
      pointStart: Date.UTC(2019, 1, 28),
      data: [
0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
         ]
      }
   ];
```

Comment: The important part is `tooltip:{shared:true}`. Did you add this part in the chart definition ?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. See lines 1-3. Or does it have to be placed somewhere else?

Comment: Do you have a live example of your problem ? JSFiddle.

Comment: Using your series on that jsfiddle this is working: https://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/4xdejvk8/1/. It looks like you are setting options to varialbes `var series = ...`. We will need to see how you are actually building your chart to offer any more assistance.